# Making a bootable OSX USB from dmg on Linux

Tags: macos, mac, usb, boot, fedora

I have 2 machines - a MacBook Pro and a desktop running Fedora, I have a USB drive and a OSX 10.8 dmg. The MacBook won't boot into OSX unfortunately, I'm trying to make a bootable mac usb to recover it.

Any insight? I've tried `dmg2img` but no success putting that image onto the usb drive.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried "[Acetoneiso](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acetoneiso/)"?

It'll convert the DMG to an ISO for you.  After that, the easiest way I know of to make a bootable USB is using DD.

> dd if=/path/to/osx.iso of=/dev/sdX && sync

**Note**: sdX is an example, you will have to check your flash drive address (usually sdb if you have only one hard disk). Do not add a partition # after that (such as sdb1).  This method is a little hard on flash drives (I have killed one or two doing this relatively frequently, but once should be fine).

If you are unfamiliar, DD is a bit by bit copy and sync just verifies that all files have been written to the usb.

Comment: why you cannot directly do DD from the .dmg to the USB ?

Comment: @Francesco - Do some research on the format differences between a `dmg` (non-standard) and `iso` (standard)

Comment: Accordign to this guide:
http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/01/install-osx-mavericks-on-pc-with-niresh.html

this should work on Mac Osx: `sudo dd if="location of Niresh disk image" of=/dev/r"identifier" bs=1m`
So why should not on linux ?

Comment: @Francesco - Never said it doesn't. Please ask your own questions rather than piggy backing off other's and providing unrelated/chatty comments.  You can also see if anyone is available in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I just want to add detail to the answer ... why you should to convert the image if it is not required ?

Comment: @Francesco - Again, look at the differences between `dmg` and `iso`. `iso` is a standard, `dmg` is often contains compressed items, where `iso`s do not. To avoid the few rare cases in which a `dmg` behaves as an `iso`, it's best to just convert it to a known valid format.  If you write the common `dmgs` (that contain compression) to a USB, many things do not handle them correctly.  So you aren't adding details, you're asking questions without researching it beyond a single case in which your point is true while ignoring the numerous cases in which it is false.

Comment: You can as well just use `hdiutil convert EXAMPLE.dmg -format RdWr -o EXAMPLE.img`, according to this [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176626).

Comment: How USB should be formatted? Partitionmap GUID/MBR? Formatting FAT/NTFS/HFS+?

Answer (score 65):

Install dmg2img

```
sudo apt-get install dmg2img
```

Convert DMG image file to ISO file

```
dmg2img -v -i /path/to/image_file.dmg -o /path/to/image_file.iso
```

Copy ISO image to USB

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/image_file.iso of=/dev/sdb && sync
```

**sdb is an example**. In your case it might be different

#### Edit

You can do the conversion and actual writing in one pass, if you don't need the .iso afterwards: it will take half the time as converting to .iso and THEN writing to the USB device. Just do:

```
sudo dmg2img -v -i /path/to/image_file.dmg -o /dev/sdb
```

Again, **sdb is an example**. In your case it might be different.

Comment: How USB should be formatted? Partitionmap GUID/MBR? Formatting FAT/NTFS/HFS+?

Comment: @Enthusiast these instructions are writing a raw disk image to the device. Its formatting and data before the operation will be overwritten and therefore don't matter.

Comment: This does not create an ISO image, it is an HFS+ image like all the other tutorials that use this program. I still have not found a workable solution.

Comment: +1 for the direct burning to usb method

Comment: I use this method to extract a disk image of a hfs+ partition from a file called BaseSystem.dmg which is part of a recovery image for macOS. I can then mount that .iso file using `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o loop BaseSystem.iso /mnt/macimage/` However if I then write that .iso file to a usb drive using dd as you describe above then that hfs+ partition in that usb drive will NOT mount. Instead I get error: `Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2, missing codepage or helper program or other error` Why will it not mount when on the USB drive? Does `dd` mess up hfs+ disk images?

Answer (score 1):

Try booting from Internet Recovery (Command + Alt + Shift + R)
and opening the installer app from Terminal.

Open Terminal in recovery and:

```
cd /Volumes/NAME-OF-YOUR-USB-STICK/
cd The-Name-Of-Your-Installer.app/Contents/MacOS
./InstallAssistant
```

The installer should load.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find another Mac, try the Disk Utility App.

You can "Restore" your 10.8 DMG to your USB drive. This will make your USB drive be bootable.

Comment: Title says "on Linux"

Answer (score 0):

usually, you just write the dmg image to the usb drive

on linux:

```
fdisk -l # find the USB drive, for example: sdb
dd if=image.dmg of=/dev/sdb bs=16M status=progress
```

on macos:

```
diskutil list # find the USB drive, for example: disk2
dd if=image.dmg of=/dev/disk2 bs=$((16 * 1024 * 1024))
```