# How can I do a fresh OSX install with only access to linux?

Tags: linux, macos

How can I do a fresh OSX install with only access to linux?

I have a mac and the hard drive had an obvious physical crash after an encounter with a strong magnet. I put a new drive in but it seems all instructions for fresh-installs on OSX make use of another mac. I have linux machines (all debian flavors if it matters) but no other macs.

[This related question](https://superuser.com/questions/505821/making-a-bootable-osx-usb-from-dmg-on-linux) is more narrow and doesn't seem to have a definitive answer anyway.

Comment: What model? Many of them let you do a network install from bare metal

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The model says A1286 but that seems to be a large range. I tried a serial number lookup and got this: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012). That sounds about right. I'll see if I can find some kind of netboot option.

Comment: Looks like you'll need access to some version of OS X - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128319/official-way-to-obtain-an-os-x-iso-file

Comment: From [how to reinstall](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) It says Option-Command-R for latest version reboot. I'll update if it works even on 2012 model.

Comment: It should, it should apparently work on anything newer than 2011

Comment: @ivanivan Thank you that basically answers the question for anyone without netboot or network access. Impossible without breaking some rule. Hopefully my system will work with netboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mac seems *just* new enough to be able to reinstall over the internet ([2010 and 2011 models would need a firmware upgrade](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT202313)). I've done this a few times in a past job and its *pretty* self explanatory, but you'd want to read [apple's docs anyway](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201314)

Install your new hard drive, then turn on while pressing the appropriate key combination - <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>
-<kbd>R</kbd> would give you internet recovery in any case.

Hold it down until you see an apple or spinning globe logo. This should then load the recovery utilities and you can be on their way.

Comment: Great. I will try it as soon as I have a chance and update here. Many thanks.

Comment: Just to note: You will get the OS the machine first shipped with, as that's the only one available without an AppleID sign-in; sign-in is not possible at that point. You can always update afterwards.

Comment: Ah. We ran out own server that hosted images iirc so that wasn't an issue. Something called munki iirc

Comment: @Tetsujin my experience matched your advice. command-option-R seems to work until the point that it tries to confirm installation. Then it just ignores you when you try to continue. Unhelpful errors are visible if you check the log. Plain command-R to install the original OS followed by an upgrade worked well. Thanks for everyone's help!